# vote early vote often - can we have the voting limit removed for private beta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, votes

I have hit my voting limit (again) and I think there is much more that needs voting.

If possible it would be great to have no voting limit for the next week or so, that way whats "good" and "bad" could be easier classified by the votes stuff get.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you get the limit removed. What would you do? You'll upvote every good post (good in your opinion) and downvote every bad post (again, in your opinion). But what would you do if there is the limit. Before upvoting every good post, you'll think about the limit and choose the *best* posts of those good. And downvote the *worst* posts of all bad posts. That will raise quality and the seriousness of your votes.

Also vote limit exist to prevent abuse. Just think that someone will automate his voting by script and upvote all the posts at once (e.g. just to get a badge or be first in voting leagues).